# is this sentence correct with hence?

Tags: grammar

I was ready to drop; however, I wasn’t going to sleep in front of the librarian and students. Hence, I looked for a spot where I could hide while sleeping.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. 'Hence' here means 'for that reason'. If you are writing in a formal style, 'hence' is recommended not to be used to start a sentence, but it is acceptable in more informal writing.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage.  When providing information in an answer, sources should be provided. If this is not done, the answer can only be taken as opinion.

Comment: Thank you for the useful reminder  @J. Taylor. As I wasn't sure if the OP was asking about the meaning or the punctuation, and as the punctuation comment was aimed at the lack of prescription, I couldn't decide which source(s) might be appropriate to cite, but you are right that I should have taken the time to research all more fully and not just rely on intuition and experience.